# "Quality comes naturally with integrity."

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-meaning

Is the title a correct way to convey that, quality is a byproduct of integrity?

Any suggestions on how to rephrase the title are welcome of course.

Comment: That's a "platitude" -- the precise choice of wording is up to the person constructing it, based on whatever subtle meanings they wish to convey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Come with* is a phrasal verb that means "to accompany; to go along with" ([The Free Dictionary)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/come+with). For example, take the well-known advice to Spider-Man that "**with** great power **comes** great responsibility." So yes, your phrase means that quality accompanies or goes along with integrity; if you have integrity, then you have quality.

While your phrase is correct, here are some other options you could consider that mean the same thing:

- "Quality follows integrity."
- "Integrity results in quality."
- "When you have integrity, you have quality."

Comment: Or "Integrity yields quality, naturally."